# Swift 3: how can I detect the touch event on UIScrollView?

Tags: swift

I used the below function to detect the touch event on scroll view.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
```

But this can't detect any touch event.
How can I detect touch event on scroll view?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set up a `tap recognizer` on your `scrollView`:

In your `viewDidLoad` add the following:

```
let scrollViewTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(scrollViewTapped))
scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(scrollViewTap)
```

Declare this function which will be called when the `scrollView` is tapped:

```
func scrollViewTapped() {
    print("scrollViewTapped")
}
```

Comment: `numberOfTapsRequired` is 1 by default (Swift 4.2, iOS 12) so no need to set it.

Answer (score 2):

In order to override the touch events you have to subclass the scroll view, like this:

```
class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("began")
    }
}
```

Then use MyScrollView as class instead of UIScrollView, like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myScrollView = MyScrollView(frame: self.view.frame)
        myScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(myScrollView)
    }
}
```

I set the background to blue so you can see that the scroll view is working.